# Passing param directly works, passing it within a object or array does not work

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a function which looks like this

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    param.on('mouseover', function(){/*Do something*/});
}

var polygon = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    //My settings
});
myFunction(polygon);
```

This works absolutely fine. But when I pass polygon within an array or object like this I get the error.

```
function myFunction(param)
{
    for(var elem in param)
    {
        elem.on('mouseover', function(){/*Do something*/});
    }
}

var polygon = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    //My settings
});
myFunction([polygon]);
```

Error is (in console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'on'
```

What  am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `for ... in` loops work a little differently than you think. The values that are yielded by the statement are actually the properties of the object that is iterated over, which in case of an Array object are the array indexes.

The below should work:

```
function myFunction(array)
{
    for(var key in array)
    {
        elem = array[key]
        elem.on('mouseover', function(){/*Do something*/});
    }
}
```

See http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/ for some more examples.